# What is the error Java ArrayLists

Tags: java, arraylist

I am throughly convinced that this is snippet of code has an error. The Java from the ground up programming book says that there is no error. This is the code:

```
ArrayList temp = new ArrayList();
temp.add("35");
temp.add(35);
```

Isn't there an error with line 2? An arrayList cannot have a string and an integer within the same ArrayList correct? Please correct me if I am wrong, I have a test on this tomorrow. Thank you all in advance!

Comment: If you have test on this..First read [Generics in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/)..you will get a more clearer picture..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is correct.

Since you haven't declared any type in `ArrayList` it allow all Objects.

Now your ArrayList as same as

```
ArrayList<Object> temp = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

And see below examples

```
ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();
temp.add("35");
temp.add(35); //compiler error, Only Strings please
```

see below example

```
ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
temp.add("35");//compiler error, Only Integers please
temp.add(35);
```

And it's highly discouraged to use Raw types, Always prefer to use with specific type.

Now in first case `ArrayList temp = new ArrayList();`, when you return it returns an Object which is unkown type. It may be an Integer or a String, you need to check it manually after you got it back from `List`

Comment: Thank you very much! You have cleared up alot for me, much thanks.

Answer (score 1):

it is correct because its a raw type means you can add any object.You can **add** anything that extends `Object` class
you can write `temp.add(x);` *where x can be any thing String,int,long Date anything that* extends `Object`

example

```
String x="";
    int x1=1;
    Date df=new Date();
temp.add(x);// will work
temp.add(x1);//will work
temp.add(df);// will work
```

Answer (score 1):

`ArrayList temp = new ArrayList();` There is no issue here. This is an `ArrayList` which will accept any data type since it is not defined specific data type (raw ArrayList).

Answer (score 0):

It is correct. Since you haven't declare any type for list, it treats all the elements as `Object` class. Your definition is

```
 ArrayList<Object>  arr=new ArrayList<>();
```

for compiler. In this case 35 will be boxed to `Integer` and "35" will be a `String`. Both `Integer` and `String` are subclass of `Object` and there wan't be any compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

yes your array list can hold both String and integer.
but array list only store objects String and Integer objects it doesnt support int primitive datatypes only objects inside arraylist

```
ArrayList<Object>  arr=new ArrayList<>();
  String s="35";
  Integer in=35;
  arr.add(in);
  arr.add(s);`
```

Answer (score 0):

In java there is something named as [Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/) which allows programmers to abstract over types.

Arraylist code internally uses it.So when you don't define any generic type the default type it takes is the `Object` class type.

And as `String` as well as `Integer` both are subclasses of Object class, so this operation is allowed according to OOPs.